# AC: Powering a 25 amp appliance from 2x20 amp breakers

Tags: wire, electrical, circuit-breaker

I want to use a 25 amp appliance but only have 20 amp breakers.

**Work around**
I am thinking of hot wiring the output of 2x20 amp breakers so that the 25A load is distributed between 2 breakers instead of one, preventing the breakers from tripping and giving me up to 40A of power to work with.

Is this possible and would it work?

**Update**
Thanks for the feedback.
I decided it is best to get an electrician around to wire a new 30A breaker, wiring and new wall socket.

Comment: Do NOT do this - the exact same question was asked recently on here...

Comment: See here, but not the one I was looking for : https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/169413/152903

Comment: What the heck sort of appliance is this?

Comment: 120V appliance - 120V line : Code Violation.  220V Appliance on a Single Phase 220 Line Code Violation. 230V Appliance 2 Phase - Code Violation (underrated breakers). In All scenarios this is a Code Violation! You can not parallel the breaker circuits (only 1 might trip and the other might not and even perhaps the thing works with one breaker tripped hmm BAD BAD BAD and just MORE BAD!).
BUY the < $20 Circuit Breaker that you need (a 30 Amp) and be done with it the RIGHT way and protect your household from burning down.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You so not want to do this. If you have a true 25A load then install the proper 30A or 40A single breaker and the proper wiring for that amperage (10AWG for 30A breaker or 8AWG for 40A breaker) in a single circuit to a listed receptacle rated for that current rating.

Here are some of the problems that you have with what you propose:

1. There is never any guarantee that both parallel breakers will split the current equally.
2. If one breaker goes open on a current overload the other breaker and circuit is left trying to source your 25A load through wiring that is rated for 20A or less. This can cause overheating. One would hope that in this case the second breaker would open but with just a 5A overload on a 20A breaker it may not trip right away.
3. In the case that you are on a split phase AC mains power system (such as used in the USA where 120VAC per phase is available) you could mistakenly try to parallel up two 20A breakers that were on opposite phases. Doing so would result in a direct short across the 240VAC and could cause lots of sparks to fly.

So....again do not do the kludge that you are proposing and install the proper single breaker/wiring/receptacle to support your 25A load in a safe and reliable way.

Comment: "lots of sparks to fly" is an understatement. You may have an enormous amount of current available at that location, and a line-to-line short will unleash an ungodly amount of energy which can easily be deadly - [arc flash](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6hpE5LYj-CY)

Comment: I so wish I could give this answer the awesome Bang Bang High Five Flashing neon lights Pay Attention Sign.

Comment: FYI - NEC Article 240.8 covers parallel breakers. They are only allowed if part of a factory assembly and listed as a unit. "Individual fuses, circuit breakers, or combinations thereof, shall not otherwise be connected in parallel."

Answer (score 4):

That is a terrible idea, and is a code violation for *a variety of reasons*.

I'm assuming you are in North America because the rest of the world uses oddball breaker sizes like 6A, 13A, 16A etc.

Circuit breakers are five dollars US, they cost less than a Starbucks latte.  Simply change the 20A breaker to a 30A, and you'll have no trouble finding a 30A 1-pole breaker.  If it's 2-pole they are even easier to find.

Now you cannot put 25A on cable intended for 20A, and you certainly can't breaker it for 30A. You need 10AWG cable.  Again you cannot parallel for more capacity. I won't get into the details of why paralleling is bad, because it's widely covered elsewhere on this diy stack.

Now what is the actual ampacity of the device?  Is it a continuous load? If so, you need to derate it, by multiplying its actual nameplate current draw by 125%. Machine designers know this and tend to aim for ampacities slightly below the magic numbers of 12A, 16A, 24A and 32A.  Which derate to 15, 20, 30 and 40A.

If your machine really is 25A then it derates to 31.5A and you would need to use a 40A breaker and 8 AWG wire. You can always use larger wire than is required, but I would not use a 40A breaker unless the device really needs it, because it makes the breaker slow to protect the device.

Comment: A 40 amp breaker on a 25 amp device would be a code violation.

Comment: @EdBeal ... no? The breaker isn't for the devices on the circuit but for the circuit itself. As long as the wiring is at a correct gauge to supply 40A, a 40A breaker is fine. You seem to be implying a breaker cannot be rated higher than the total draw you connect to that circuit at a given time, which is definitely not true.

Comment: The problem here is the op is paralleling a definite NO NO!

Comment: @Harper Great that you pointed out the code violation! Also only one breaker might trip depending on how this appliance works - continuous load or not continuous - if only one breaker trips the other carries the entire load and is a fire / hazardous event waiting to happen. He cannot gang them in the box together either because Odd is one phase and Even is another phase meaning he has two phases side by side (that would be shorted phases) so getting them to gang together op would need to skip a space - not possible to gang (properly).

Comment: NEC 422.11.E.3 the max over current device is 150% the next size breaker up can be used. So after doing the math a 40 amp can be used 150% of 25 = 37.5 so a 40 could be used but no larger. Paralleling is allowed but it is required to be a factory assembled unit and listed as a unit NEC 240.8 individual. Fuses/circuit breakers shall not be used in parallel.

Comment: @Harper Its an inverter welding machine. That's right, it doesn't have a continuous duty cycle. The cable/plug attached to the inverter is 230V 16A. But the electrician I got around says its the spike from the inverter which requires it to be connected to a higher amperage breaker.

Comment: @TheLegendaryCopyCoder OH!  Well, that changes **everything**.   Ask a new question, and this time ***lead*** with the fact it's a welder. Welders are so special they have their own rules.   You can't fix this question, you asked in the general and we answered in the general.